# Is it possible to populate an Entity Framework custom property from a web service?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database-first generated Entity Framework model.  My User object has the following properties: Access, CustomID, Name.  All of these are populated from the database.  However, the source of data for the Name field is changing to a web service.  I will need to remove the generated Name property, replace it with a custom name property, and populate that from the proxy object I use to access the web service.  However, in order to access that proxy object, I need the ControllerContext which has the proxy object loaded.

I've been mucking around with several options, but none of them seem to work.  Any ideas?

TIA!

```
public partial class User
{

    public string Name
    {
        get { return WSCache.GetEmployeeName(this.CustomID); } //WSCache is not loaded!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a method in my helper class and made sure to call that every time I needed to pull a User object from the database, which would populate a custom Name property in the partial class.

```
public partial class User
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}

    public static User GetUser(EmployeeCache empCache, ITestRepository repo, string customId)
    {
        User user = repo.Single<User>(u => u.CustomId== customId);

        user.Name = empCache.GetEmployeeName(customId);

        return user;
    }
```